# WSL2 no longer starting with bash colors

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, wsl2

Until today when I started WSL2 with Ubuntu on Windows, I would get the pretty colors of the bash terminal. I think with today's update that no longer happens. Instead, the shell starts uncolored. If I run `bash` in the terminal, then it works. What changed, and how do I get back to where it was before?

[image: Screenshot showing initial uncolored prompt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure your settings files are in order. In my case, I had recently created a `~/.bash_profile`, which meant that my `~/.bashrc` was not being loaded (See [related answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login)).

Deleting `~/.bash_profile` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `~/.bashrc` and uncomment the following line:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

so it becomes:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Save the file, and for this to take immediate effect enter the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This helped me identify the issue. I had recently created and defined an alias in `~/.bash_profile`, and as a result my `.bashrc` was not being run. Moving the alias to `.bashrc` and deleting `.bash_profile` fixed it.