# Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 no longer starting with bash colors

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, colors, wsl2

I'm using Windows Terminal. Added alias to `.bashrc` colors disappeared. Actually, I did a dumb thing - overwritten `.bashrc` with

```
echo 'alias kubectl="minikube kubectl --"' > ~/.bashrc
```

Tried from [WSL2 no longer starting with bash colors](https://superuser.com/questions/1545052/wsl2-no-longer-starting-with-bash-colors/1546531#1546531?newreg=a9bca2acd5f844a69f85dc968a700e2f)
Next solutions and none seems to work:

- Added `force_color_prompt=yes` into `~/.bashrc`
- Moved all things into `~/.bash_profile`
- Deleted both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`

Also did next and no luck:

- Restarted Windows Terminal
- Stopped wsl by executing `wsl --shutdown`. Closed `Windows Terminal` and opened again.

Comment: @Peregrino69 please answer the question as `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and I mark as accepted answer. It worked without any restart or whatever. I have double tested. Removed .bashrc and colors disappeared. Did  `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and again in a new tab of Windows Terminal colors start work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ensure you're not logging in as root. Root user usually doesn't have anything fancy going on.

If this happens when logging in as a standard user, you can restore the default `.bashrc` file:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Then source it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will restore the default Bash behavior without logging out/in or restarting the system.

Comment: Many thanks again. It worked. Sorry my reputation is not enough to vote up.

Comment: @AlexK It's fine, friend, I'm not here really for rep, just to learn and keep my own knowledge fresh(ish) - answering questions is a great tool for that :-)